# Is there a way to automatically install all dependencies from a custom sdk in new project?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, nuget

this is my first time asking a question here so be kind. I have a custom sdk built which depends on other packages such as

1. StackExchanges.Redis
2. Confluent Kafka
3. Microsoft Extensions

What I'm looking to achieve:

When I install my custom package from the nuget packages I install all dependencies on installation. I do this because I know what is needed. Is it possible have this set up automatically such that when I download my nuget package it downloads all dependencies in addition? Thanks.

Comment: with transient dependencies, they should be there.